# Why resultCode return 0 in changeActivityForesult

Tags: android

I have 3 Activity: A,B,C. A have button `nextB`, here is code in A

```html
class A extends AppCompatActivity {
...
  nextB.setOnClickListener(...
    Intent in = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    startActivityForResult(in, 8);
  );

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 8 && resultCode == 9) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

B have two buttons: `nextC` and `resetB`. Here is code in B:

```js
class B extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
      nextC.setOnClickListener(...
        Intent in = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
        startActivityForResult(in, 9);
      );
      resetB.setOnClickListener(...
        Intent in = new Intent(B.this, B.class);
        startActivityForResult(in, 8);
        finish();
      );
      
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
              if (requestCode == 9 && resultCode == 10) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(9, intent);
                finish();
              }
        }
    }
```

and in C I have button `finished`. Here is code in C

```js
class C extends AppCompatActivity {
...
  finished.setOnClickListener(...
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(10, intent);
    finish();
  );   
}
```

When I change screen from `A` with follow one `nextB`-> `nextC` ( click in `B`) -> `finished` `C` will move to `A` and show toast OK.

But when I change screen with follow two `nextB`->`resetB` ( click in `B`) -> `nextC` ( click in `B`) -> `finished` `C` will move to `A`but it not show toast Ok.
When I debug `resultCode` in A return 0. 
I try remove `finish()` when click `resetB` but it return same result ( don't show dialog Ok in A).

What happened in here and how I can show dialog when change screen with follow tow?
Thank you so much!

Comment: why you intent in same class in class B ?  `Intent in = new Intent(B.this, B.class);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Call only one result in activityA

```
class A extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
      nextB.setOnClickListener(...
        Intent in = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        startActivityForResult(in, 8);
      );

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if (requestCode== 8) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }


        }
    }
```

Using StartActivityForwardResult in b to C and set result in reset B button Like button

```
 resetB.setOnClickListener(...
        Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
      );

nextC.setOnClickListener(
        Intent in = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
                                    startActivity(intent);

        );
```

and in C Activity set result code as a same in you define in A activity

```
class C extends AppCompatActivity {
...
  finished.setOnClickListener(...
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
  );   
}
```